# is possible to zoom in/out a UIImageView in custom cell of a UICollectionView only when pinch the cell's imageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell, gesture, pinch

I have a CollectionView that have one custom cell.

I want to zoom in/out imageView in cell, so i add pinch gesture at CollectionView.m

when i add gesture to self.collectionView, like this:

```
[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
```

it works!  my cell.imageView can zoom in/out, but when i pinch other place(not in cell's imageView, my cell.imageView still zoom in/out with the gesture, I want the cell.imageView zoom in/out just when user pinch the cell.imageView, so i try to add gesture use this code:

```
[cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work. Nothing happen when i pinch the cell's imageView.

so my question is, is possible to zoom in/out the cell's imageView only when user pinch the cell's imageView? not other place.

Comment: A tip: Add a uiscroll view in collection cell and add image in uiscrollview. now use uiscrollview for zooming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]Collection view cell

```
//cell.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Cell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollview;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;

- (void)setup;

@end


//cell.m

#import "Cell.h"
#define MAXIMUM_SCALE 3.0
#define MINIMUM_SCALE    1.0

@interface Cell()<UIScrollViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation Cell

- (void)setup {

    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(zoomImage:)];
    self.imageview.gestureRecognizers = @[pinch];
    self.imageview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.scrollview.delegate = self;

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma  mark  - Scrollview Delegate Method

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self.imageview;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma mark - Custom Methods

- (void)zoomImage:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
    || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        NSLog(@"gesture.scale = %f", gesture.scale);

        CGFloat currentScale = self.frame.size.width / self.bounds.size.width;
        CGFloat newScale = currentScale * gesture.scale;

        if (newScale < MINIMUM_SCALE) {
            newScale = MINIMUM_SCALE;
        }
        if (newScale > MAXIMUM_SCALE) {
            newScale = MAXIMUM_SCALE;
        }

        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(newScale, newScale);
        self.imageview.transform = transform;
        self.scrollview.contentSize = self.imageview.frame.size;

    }

}

@end
```

ViewController files

```
//ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController


@end



//ViewController.m[![enter image description here][1]][1]


#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Cell.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray  *imageArray;

@end

@implementation ViewController

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma mark - Collectionview Datasource Methods

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return self.imageArray.count;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Cell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setup];
    cell.imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma mark - Lifecycle method

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _imageArray = @[ @"1.jpg", @"1.jpg" ];
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionView.delegate = self;

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Note : You need to create an IBOutlet for scrollview, image view and collection view from storyboard.

Comment: If it works, great; but, this is a verbose and complex solution. Simply set up a pinch gesture recognizer and transform the view in its handler. If you set the pinch gesture's delegate to the cell and the handler on the cell subclass... If not that, then, in the pinch gesture's handler, identify which cell to scale by its pinch points. Need code? I just did this today.

Comment: when you implement this way that time your image is not zoom as you want.

Answer (score 3):

By default, Image view's property `userInteractionEnabled` is set to NO, which disable all gesture recognizers. Setting the property to YES should solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to add use scrollview inside cell and image view in scroll view
and enable the zoom for the scroll view not for your entire collectionview

```
 scrollViewMain.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
    scrollViewMain.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    scrollViewMain.clipsToBounds = NO;
    scrollViewMain.delegate = self;
```

i think this will help you