# All Gestures in Array of Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have say 10 images which I have to change on swipe or scroll and use double tap to zoom at particular position and pan will work when image get zoomed else not and side by side pinch gesture should be maintained.

For this I apply logic but there is conflict between swipe and pan gesture so I drop the concept of swipe, I use scrollview and imageview is placed inside but when one image is zoomed and I scroll horizontally next image also get zoomed.

Though I put condition to get the image on same size on scrollview did scroll but wont get work.

I used collectionview and inside cell I placed scrollview then image and apply all the gestures but wont work.

Comment: hint: set delegate and and implement `UIGestureRecognizer` delegate methods.

Comment: Try CollectionView. Here is a sample :
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33546395/is-possible-to-zoom-in-out-a-uiimageview-in-custom-cell-of-a-uicollectionview-on

Comment: I tried that code but its not working.mentioned in question also..@krishnanunni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to krishnanunni's Answered link From: "[is possible to zoom in/out a UIImageView in custom cell of a UICollectionView only when pinch the cell's imageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33546395/is-possible-to-zoom-in-out-a-uiimageview-in-custom-cell-of-a-uicollectionview-on)".I modified Bit And it works well[Arrangement Same as from Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KvwY.png)

```
in gallerycell.m

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollview;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;

- (void)setup;

@end


//cell.m

#import "Cell.h"
#define MAXIMUM_SCALE 3.0
#define MINIMUM_SCALE    1.0

@interface Cell()<UIScrollViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation Cell


- (void)setup {

    CGFloat newScale = MINIMUM_SCALE;
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(newScale, newScale);
    self.imgView.transform = transform;
    self.scrView.contentSize = self.imgView.frame.size;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    doubleTap.delegate = self;
    [self.scrView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    ZoomCheck = YES;


    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(zoomImage:)];
    pinch.delegate = self;
    self.imgView.gestureRecognizers = @[pinch];
    self.imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.scrView.delegate = self;

}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self.imgView;
}
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // The scroll view has zoomed, so we need to re-center the contents
    [self centerScrollViewContents];
}

- (void)centerScrollViewContents {
    // This method centers the scroll view contents also used on did zoom
    CGSize boundsSize = self.scrView.bounds.size;
    CGRect contentsFrame = self.imgView.frame;

    if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0f;
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
    }

    if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0f;
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
    }

    self.imgView.frame = contentsFrame;
}


- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    NSLog(@"TAPCALLED");
    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:self.imgView];
    NSLog(@"x %f y %f",location.x, location.y);
    CGFloat currentScale = self.frame.size.width / self.bounds.size.width;

    NSLog(@"%.f",currentScale);
    CGPoint pointInView = [gesture locationInView:self.imgView];
    if(ZoomCheck){

        // Get a zoom scale that's zoomed in slightly, capped at the maximum zoom scale specified by the scroll view
        CGFloat newZoomScale = self.scrView.zoomScale * 3.0f;
        newZoomScale = MIN(newZoomScale, self.scrView.maximumZoomScale);

        // Figure out the rect we want to zoom to, then zoom to it
        CGSize scrollViewSize = self.scrView.bounds.size;

        CGFloat w = scrollViewSize.width / newZoomScale;
        CGFloat h = scrollViewSize.height / newZoomScale;
        CGFloat x = pointInView.x - (w / 2.0f);
        CGFloat y = pointInView.y - (h / 2.0f);

        CGRect rectToZoomTo = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

        [self.scrView zoomToRect:rectToZoomTo animated:YES];


        ZoomCheck=NO;
    }
    else{

        CGFloat newZoomScale = self.scrView.zoomScale / 3.0f;
        newZoomScale = MIN(newZoomScale, self.scrView.minimumZoomScale);

        // Figure out the rect we want to zoom to, then zoom to it
        CGSize scrollViewSize = self.scrView.bounds.size;

        CGFloat w = scrollViewSize.width * newZoomScale;
        CGFloat h = scrollViewSize.height * newZoomScale;
        CGFloat x = pointInView.x - (w * 2.0f);
        CGFloat y = pointInView.y - (h * 2.0f);

        CGRect rectToZoomTo = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

        [self.scrView zoomToRect:rectToZoomTo animated:YES];


        ZoomCheck=YES;
    }


}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma mark - Custom Methods

- (void)zoomImage:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    if (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan == gesture.state ||
        UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged == gesture.state) {

        // Use the x or y scale, they should be the same for typical zooming (non-skewing)
        float currentScale = [[gesture.view.layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale.x"] floatValue];

        // Variables to adjust the max/min values of zoom
        float minScale = 1.0;
        float maxScale = 3.0;
        float zoomSpeed = .5;

        float deltaScale = gesture.scale;

        // You need to translate the zoom to 0 (origin) so that you
        // can multiply a speed factor and then translate back to "zoomSpace" around 1
        deltaScale = ((deltaScale - 1) * zoomSpeed) + 1;

        // Limit to min/max size (i.e maxScale = 2, current scale = 2, 2/2 = 1.0)
        //  A deltaScale is ~0.99 for decreasing or ~1.01 for increasing
        //  A deltaScale of 1.0 will maintain the zoom size
        deltaScale = MIN(deltaScale, maxScale / currentScale);
        deltaScale = MAX(deltaScale, minScale / currentScale);

        CGAffineTransform zoomTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(gesture.view.transform, deltaScale, deltaScale);
        gesture.view.transform = zoomTransform;

        // Reset to 1 for scale delta's
        //  Note: not 0, or we won't see a size: 0 * width = 0
        gesture.scale = 1;
    }

   }


@end
```

Note:Zoomcheck is a bool to check if it is doubletapped and zoom previously.

Add UICollectionView And inside the cell add scrollview and then imageview.the arrangement is shown in link above

Answer (score 0):

Try using scroll view delegates. Do not uses pan gesture just use double tap zoom and swipe gesture. It works fine.

Comment: that i know but i wont pan also .do help me with that

Comment: Scroll view delegates helps you to pan as well. Use - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    
    return yourImageView;
}